# When I scroll up and down on a mobile device my skills chart wont disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const skillsLink = document.querySelector(".page-header li:nth-child(1) a");
const skillsClose = document.querySelector(".skills-close");
const windowOpened = "window-opened";

skillsLink.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.body.classList.toggle(windowOpened);
});

skillsClose.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle(windowOpened);
});
```

```css
.title {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: 'Mansalva', cursive;
}

:root {
  --black: #1a1a1a;
  --white: rgb(255, 255, 255) ;
  --red: #e93451;
  --transition-delay: 0.85s;
  --transition-delay-step: 0.3s;
}


* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.f {
    font-family: 'Knewave', cursive;
}

.flex-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.justify-content-center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.justify-content-between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.justify-content-around {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.align-items-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.align-items-end {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.flex-grow-1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.position-relative {
  position: relative;
}

.position-fixed {
  position: ;
}

.position-absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.text-black {
  color: var(--black);
}

.text-white {
  color: var(--white);
}

.bg-black {
  background: var(--black);
}

.bg-white {
  background: var(--white);
}

.bg-red {
  background: var(--red);
}

/* BODY
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
body {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  overflow: scroll;
   font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

/* HEADER
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.page-header {
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e93451;
}

.page-header li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

 .page-header .logo {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: color 0.3s;
  font-family: 'Knewave', cursive;
}

.window-opened .page-header .logo {
  color: var(--black);
  transition-delay: 0.8s;
}

/* HEADING
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.heading {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

/* CONTACT
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.contact {
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

/* SECTION
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.skills-section {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.window-opened .skills-section {
  transform: none;
}

[data-slideIn="to-top"] {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

[data-slideIn="to-bottom"] {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

[data-slideIn="to-right"] {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.creator {
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.creator span {
  color: #e31b23;
}

.skills-close {
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.chart-wrapper {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  max-width: 500px;
}

.chart-levels li {
  padding: 15px;
}

.chart-skills li {
  width: 12%;
  height: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  transition: height 0.65s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.91, 0.24, 1.16);
}

.window-opened .chart-skills li:nth-child(1) {
  height: 80%;
  transition-delay: var(--transition-delay);
}

.window-opened .chart-skills li:nth-child(2) {
  height: 60%;
  transition-delay: calc(
    var(--transition-delay) + var(--transition-delay-step)
  );
}

.window-opened .chart-skills li:nth-child(3) {
  height: 68%;
  transition-delay: calc(
    var(--transition-delay) + var(--transition-delay-step) * 2
  );
}

.window-opened .chart-skills li:nth-child(4) {
  height: 52%;
  transition-delay: calc(
    var(--transition-delay) + var(--transition-delay-step) * 3
  );
}

.window-opened .chart-skills li:nth-child(5) {
  height: 42%;
  transition-delay: calc(
    var(--transition-delay) + var(--transition-delay-step) * 4
  );
}

.chart-skills li::before {
  content: attr(data-height);
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  color: var(--white);
}

.chart-skills span {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(40px) rotate(45deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  html {
    font-size: 12;
    overflow: scroll;
  }

  .chart-levels li {
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 0;
  }
}




.product h2 {
  font-family: 'Hammersmith One', sans-serif;
}

.product p {
  font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;

}

/* smaller screen sizes, eg. mobile devices */
.menu {
  display:none;
}

.bio{
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding:30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Gochi Hand', cursive;
}

.bio2{
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin:20px;
  padding:30px;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-family: 'Gochi Hand', cursive;

}


main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
 
.product {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: 5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius:5px;
  margin:20px;
  padding:30px;
}


/* larger screen sizes, eg. desktops */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  {
 
  }
  

  .menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin:10px;
    list-style:none;
  }
  
  .menu > li {
    margin:30px;
  }

 .main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

 
 .product {
    flex:1;
    border-radius:5px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:10px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mansalva&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gochi+Hand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Paytone+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hammersmith+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    

    
    
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Knewave&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
<body class="position-fixed d-flex flex-column text-white bg-red">
  <header class="page-header">
    <nav class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <a href="" class="logo"><strong>Michael Peavy</strong></a>
      <div class="f">
      <ul class="d-flex">
        <li>
       

   <a href="">Skills</a>
        </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <h1 class="title">
    Web Devloper
  </h1>

 <div class = "main">
  <section class="product">
        

   <h2>A as in Apple</h2>
   <p>
    We take out fruit very seriously at ABC, that is why
       the A in ABC is for Apple. Try our new AppleBook App,
    the coolest new technology disrupting the fruit industry.

   This is the Uber of Apples! 
   </p>
  </section>
  <section class="product">
   <i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave fa-5x"></i>
   <h2>B as in Bail</h2>
   <p>
    Do you need Bail! Our new BailFace app will provide you
    with lawyers and bail money at the push of a button. Its the 
    Facebook of bail bonds!
   </p>
  </section>
  <section class="product">
   <i class="fas fa-utensils fa-5x"></i>
   <h2>C as in Curry</h2>

   <p>
    Fancy some curry! Our new HurryCurry app will provide curry
    cooked by Italian chefs right to your door. Its the AirBnB of curry!
   </p>
  </section>
  </div>

  <div class="bio">
    <p>
        I’m a web developer. I spend my whole day, practicallyevery day, experimenting with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript; dabbling with Python and Ruby; and inhaling a wide variety of potentially useless information through a few hundred RSS feeds. I build websites that delight and inform. I do it well.
    </p>
  </div>

    <div class="bio2">
    <p>
        I’m curious, and I enjoy work that challenges me to learn something new and stretch in a different direction. I do my best to stay on top of changes in the state of the art so that I can meet challenges with tools well suited to the job at hand. The list of projects I follow on GitHub will give you a good idea of the types of tools I’d prefer to be using, and my Instapaper “Starred” list will give you a glimpse into the reading  material I find interesting enough to share.
    </p>
  </div>


    


    


  <div class="f">
  <a class="position-absolute contact" href="mailto:contact@michaelpeavy.com">Email</a>
  </div>
  <section class="position-absolute d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-black bg-white skills-section" data-slideIn="to-top">
    <button class="position-absolute skills-close" aria-label="Close Skills Section">✕</button>
    <div class="d-flex chart-wrapper">
      <ul class="chart-levels">
        <li>Expert</li>
        <li>Advanced</li>
        <li>Intermediate</li>
        <li>Beginner</li>
        <li>Novice</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="d-flex justify-content-around align-items-end flex-grow-1 text-center bg-black chart-skills">
        <li class="position-relative bg-red" data-height="80%">
          <span class="position-absolute w-100">CSS</span>
        </li>
        <li class="position-relative bg-red" data-height="60%">
          <span class="position-absolute w-100">HTML</span>
        </li>
        <li class="position-relative bg-red" data-height="68%">
          <span class="position-absolute w-100">JavaScript</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <small class="position-absolute creator">Made with <span>❤</span> by <a href="http://georgemartsoukos.com/" target="_blank">George Martsoukos</a>
    </small>
  </section>
</body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Im new to web development experimenting with building a portfolio app looking for help from a experienced developer. If you click skills in the right hand corner on a mobile device, it dosent dissappear it only moves. How do i get the tab to completely disappear when I click the x?--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the display of your skill page (the page that come and go) to none and block when user clicks

i code a little [thing](https://codepen.io/alibalouchi/pen/gOYJrYX?&editable=true) for you to get points of what i'm saying.

html:

```
<div id="change">Helllllllllo man</div>

<button type="button" onclick="change()">Change</button>
```

css:

```
.close{
  display: none;
}
```

js:

```
const change = () => {
  document.getElementById("change").classList.toggle("close")
}
```